# Crash when app is updated

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I currently have my app on the AppStore, and current version is 1.4.
The last version was 1.3, and when users are updating from 1.3 -> 1.4 they have a crash when they use it, however I notice that if they uninstalled then reinstall it from scratch the bug disappear.
Is there anyway to simulate this behavior ?

I already try to checkout the 1.3 version, install it from Xcode on my device then update my App to 1.4 but I was not able to reproduce the crash.
Do you know any way to simulate the update of my app ?

Also, if I publish the 1.5 version on testFlight and then update my app from 1.4 Appstore to 1.5 testFlight, is my app deleted then reinstall or does it update it like it does when I did 1.3 Appstore -> 1.4 Appstore ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you using CoreData? If you change something in your model without doing a lightweight migration, for instance, when your app starts it sees that the model is not the same and it doesn't know how to deal with the mapping of current model to the new and it can cause the app to crash

Comment: Do you use CoreData, and updated your model? Did you saved value into NSUserDefault and changed the type of object saved?

Comment: if you are storing data locally with Sqlite/Core data and there is any update in database structure, you will need to manage it. With Coredata, will need implement coredata migraton.

Comment: I'm not using CoreData, only NSUserDefault, and yes I did add a new value in my 1.4 : `let tutorialIsDone = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("tuto")`
But I thought that it can only be true if it exists or false if it's false or if it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

To handle this situation, first check for Sqlite and Coredata changes. If you have changed or altered any tables then you need to provide data migration.

In your case where you have not used it, check for crashlogs from iTunes portal. Symbolication of Crashlog will explain the crash in much better way.

To simulate the same, install the application of version 1.3 from store. Now sign the version 1.4 with distribution certificate and ad-hoc profile. Load it on test flight. Install this new version to upgrade from 1.3 to 1.4. This will create the same steps and you will be able to re-produce the issue.